# show asymtotic normality

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, asymptotics, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ be a sample from a multivariate normal distribution, with mean vector $\mathbf{\mu}$ (n by 1 column vector, all elements equal to $\mu$) and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ (diagonals all equal to $\sigma^2$ and off-diagonals all equal to $\rho\sigma^2$, $\rho>0$).

Consider $y=\overline{x}+ks$, where $\overline{x}$ is the sample mean and $s$ is the sample standard deviation and $k$ is a known constant. Show $y$ is normally distributed as $n$ is large.

Could anyone share some ideas here? I kind of know how to show it when $\rho=0$, not for $\rho>0$. Thanks.

Comment: If you "kind of know how" to show it when $\rho = 0$, then why don't you start by actually (not kind of) showing us that.